# Create lamda container image from ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm recently started exploring aws lambda for implementing one of the usecase. I have already developed an application based on Ubuntu OS and it is working fine in containers. When I started exploring building custom image with lambda, they are providing Amazon linux & ami varients. But my application already developed based on Ubuntu and I would like to use it with lambdas. Kindly provide references or samples that will help me.

Comment: if you are talking about docker containers. Did you consider running the docker containers in Amazon Fargate where you don't have to manage an EC2 instance to run the container?